# Is it possible to have result and row count of the result in adjacent columns?

Tags: mysql, sql, jdbc

Lets say we a table `t1` as

```
>desc t1;
      id     int 
     name    varchar(30)
```

and

```
>select count(*) from t1;
      count(*)
       10
```

Is it possible to fetch the result as

```
id   name   count
1    abc     10
2    def     10
.     .      .
.     .      .
.     .      .
```

Where the actual result columns `id` `name` and the count of the result query `count` are in the same resultset. Is it possible that way? 
The basic idea is to fetch the result row count along with the result, instead of having to query the database for the count separately. Even sub queries are also fine.

Thank you.

Comment: `count` is the no. of rows of the total resultset not just the current row, so it has to be constant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.  It's also quite efficient due to the way MySQL optimizes stuff

```
  SELECT t.*, 
         (select count(*) from t1) as count
    FROM t1 t
```

Comment: @Olloe Jones Is it possible to return the multiple columns in this query: (select count(*), SUM(COLUMN1) from t1) as count

Comment: Yes. that's possible, but SUM() won't be as efficient as COUNT().

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * FROM t1, (SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM t1) t2
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
select id, name, (select count(*) from t1) as cnt from t1;
```